# How to not do anything after until an OK button is clicked in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an $.ajax() function that requests something with a string location.

Assume result.location = "Somewhere" on the ajax response, but theoretically it could be any string.

On success(result) it does:

```
Line 1: alert("Hello There");
Line 2: alert("Look Here" + result.location); // Look here Somewhere
```

What happens is an alert box for "Hello There" pops up and "Look here" alert box is not shown until AFTER the user closes the "Hello There" alert box.

However, if for Line 1 instead of an alert I have a div instead of an alert box that shows up for example:

```
<div>Hello There <input type="button">OK</input></div>
```

So instead I have:

```
Line 1: showDivAlert();
Line 2: alert("Look Here" + result.location); // Look here Somewhere
```

Then what happens is the div shows up and the alert "Look Here" pops up. What could I put in function "showDivAlert()" such that any code below showDivAlert() will not get executed until the user clicks the "OK" button?

NOTE: key here is to preserve the result.location string of the ajax request

Comment: preserving the reference to `result.location` may not be needed as long as the value persists - i.e. it could be passed as a string argument to the `showDivAlert` callback: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10746382/1081234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML so that you have:

```
<div>Hello There <input type="button" id="alert-ok">OK</input></div>
```

Now you can target the button through the #alert-ok id.

If you're using jQuery, just attach an event:

```
showDivAlert();
$("#alert-ok").click(function() {
    //do work
});
```

Comment: The problem with what you currently posted above is the result.location is lost by doing that.

Comment: If you have it within the callback of your ajax request, it won't be lost. You can refer to result locally, since this is a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than defining your post-OK code in the same block which shows the dialog, the event handler of pressing the OK button in your custom dialog should trigger any additional behavior.

Something like this:

```
<div>Hello There <input type="button" onclick="okClicked()" value="OK"/></div>
```

---

```
function okClicked() {
    alert('Look Here');
}
```

Comment: The problem with what you currently posted above is the result.location is lost by doing that.

Answer (score -1):

`alert()` in javascript effectively blocks the execution thread, resulting in the next line of code not being executed until the dialog is closed.

In contrast, your `showDivAlert();` will not block the thread and continue executing as normal. To fix this, you should add callback functionality to your method.

Similar to that of `$.ajax()`, where `success` does not get executed *until there is a valid response from the server*; you could add an argument like so:

```
function showDivAlert(callbackOK_){
    //render a fancy popup with a #btn-ok
    $('#btn-ok').click(callbackOK_);//attach the callback passed
}
```

*You pointed out on another answer that `result.location` was "lost" - instead it simply was not available in the execution scope of the callback function.*

```
showDivAlert(function(){
    alert("Look Here" + result.location);
});
```

[Fiddle'd](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/PNAxn/)